# React Native <ActivityIndicator/> not visible

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have the simplest component that renders ActivityIndicator but it's not showing on the screen.

```
export default ({}) => {
  return (
    <ActivityIndicator testID="myLoader" animating size="large"/>;
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So after a while I realized the problem was the `testID` property. Apparently `ActivityIndicator` doesn't support testID. Once I removed it, it started working.